# Windows 10/11 Explorer - How to generate text on explorer's background

Tags: shell, windows-explorer, windows-explorer-integration

I want to print some information in the background or title or columns of certain or all folders.

For example, when I enter the folder of a .git project, I want to be able to show which branch is active somewhere in the explorer window with programmatically (for example BHO) or with a cmd script (for example, "`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`").

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could try to get the window handle, and then set set the title (branch name) using `SetWindowText`. It's doesn't solve all the requirements, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in order to use SetWindowText, don't I need to constantly scan explorer processes with a service application? This is not a good solution in terms of performance. But it's still a solution :)

Comment: You could create a hook, and check when a new window is created/closed etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN